# Loading Models with INNER JOIN

Tags: phalcon

Let's say I have a `Phalcon\Mvc\Model` that I load using `::findFirst($id)`.

How can I swap in a custom query that would load the model row and do INNER JOIN on some other table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you can use the Query builder for simple joins like:

```
<?php

//Getting a whole set
$robots = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->join('RobotsParts')
    ->orderBy('Robots.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

//Getting the first row
$robots = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->join('RobotsParts')
    ->orderBy('Robots.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

Or PHQL example from the documentation:

```
<?php

$phql = "SELECT Robots.*
    FROM Robots JOIN RobotsParts p
    ORDER BY Robots.name LIMIT 20";
$result = $manager->executeQuery($phql);
```

By default, an INNER JOIN is assumed. You can specify the type of JOIN in the query though.

Reference: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder

**Then** I'd overload model's findFirst() method to utilize the above code and assign result values to model's properties.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd rather leave findFirst behaviour untouched. Is there a way to tell the Phalcon\Mvc\Model() to use my custom query?

Comment: Why not do Model::findOneWithJoin() instead

Answer (score 3):

You are able to do this, you need to use the query static method on a Model which extends the Phalcon MVC Model class.

```
    $followingUsers = Users::query()
        ->leftJoin('Common\WideZike\Models\UsersFollowers', 'Common\WideZike\Models\Users.id = Common\WideZike\Models\UsersFollowers.followingId')
        ->where('Common\WideZike\Models\UsersFollowers.followerId = :userId:', array('userId' => $user->getId()))
        ->orderBy('Common\WideZike\Models\UsersFollowers.addedDate DESC')
        ->execute();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$activations = UserActivations::query()
    ->columns("UserActivations.id")
    ->leftJoin("Deals", "d.id = UserActivations.dealId", "d") 
    ->where("UserActivations.state = 1")
    ->execute();
```

Comment: if you rightjoin how do you get right joined table columns into the model ?