# PhalconPHP Scanning error when joining tables

Tags: php, orm, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm trying to join two tables in a service, using the query() method of a Phalcon\Mvc\Model object. Here's my code:

```
$result = $this->templateModel->query()
                            ->columns('\Render\Model\Templates.* ')
                            ->leftJoin('\Render\Model\Branches.*', '\Render\Model\Templates.branchId = b.Branches.id', 'b')
                            ->where("branchId = :branchId:")
                            ->bind(['branchId' => $this->branchData['id']])
                            ->execute()
                            ->toArray();
```

However, when loading the page, I get the following error:

```
 Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception: Scanning error before '\Render\Model\Br...' when parsing: SELECT \Render\Model\Templates.* FROM [Render\Model\Templates] LEFT JOIN [\Render\Model\Branches.*] AS [b] ON \Render\Model\Templates.branchId = b.Branches.id WHERE branchId = :branchId: (187) in /home/vis/projects/stm/app/Service/BranchService.php on line 61
```

The syntax I used comes from [this Stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802328/phalconphp-database-joins-in-orm) (granted, it's not the newest post, but I'm still using Phalcon 2.0.13.

Researching the problem mostly returns results about forbidden semicolumns in the query ([example1](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/3160), [example2](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10691)), but that's not the issue in my case.

With the join line commented, the query works fine, so the problem must lie in it. Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Change `'\Render\Model\Branches.*'` to `'\Render\Model\Branches'`. You need to define the table you want to join with. Not the columns you want to select from the joining table

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm seriously absent-minded recently...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT \Render\Model\Templates.* 
FROM [Render\Model\Templates] 
LEFT JOIN [\Render\Model\Branches.*] AS [b] ON \Render\Model\Templates.branchId = b.Branches.id 
WHERE branchId = :branchId:
```

I assume that you know SQL a bit. Even if it is PhQL, you probably see part of `LEFT JOIN [\Render\Model\Branches.*]`, which looks quite suspicious. It is not possible to join table to column in this declaration. Joins happen between two tables always.

A simle fix of:

```
// -------------------------------v (removed ".*")
->leftJoin('\Render\Model\Branches', '\Render\Model\Templates.branchId = b.Branches.id', 'b')
```

should fix your problem, assuming you have properly declared `\Render\Model\Branches` model.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `\Render\Model\Branches` Also you should use model relation alias so you can do something like:

```
$modelsManager->registerNamespaceAlias('M', 'Render\Model');
```

And then just use `M:Branches` etc

Comment: or just use `Branches::class` instead of typing all the namespace stuff